# How can I do let the jar programme run more like a native programme?

Tags: linux, terminal, java

Here is the problems, I have a jar programme, which help me to do something amazing...
I run it on terminal like this:

```
jar /application/amazing.jar
```

It runs, but it seems that take my terminal to another environment, 
if I use the up arrow key to find the last commend I type in the java application, I can't find it back.

Comment: So you mean WHILE the program is running you can not use the arrow key functionality? In that case the functionality must be provided by the java program. If it doesn't either request them to add the feature - or try a workaround yourself...

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the command is really `java /application/amazing.jar` as `jar` is the command to maintain jar files not execute them.  If you really use `jar` to run the file, use the second option and replace `java` with `jar.

Just run the command `chmod +x /application/amazing.jar` once.  This will make the jar executable.   After that you should be able to run the jar using the command `/application/amazing.jar` or `amazing.jar` if `/application` is included in your path.

An alternative approach is to write a short script to run your jar.  For example `/usr/local/bin/amazing` which would be run using the command `amazing` could contain:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
java /application/amazing.jar
```

The first approach is simpler, but can not do any setup required before running the jar.  The second approach can handle setup required before the jar is run.  Just add the setup before the jar command.  They can be combined and the `java` command could be removed from the script.

Answer (score 0):

### jarwrapper

sudo apt-get install jarwrapper

Run executable Java .jar files

Jarwrapper sets up binfmt-misc to run executable jar files
using the installed java runtime.

It also includes a /usr/share/jarwrapper/java-arch.sh script
to convert Debian architecture names into java names to locate
libjvm.so